# Login to adfs through openam using java application

Tags: adfs2.0, openam

I have configured adfs as identity provider and openam as service provider but how to test whether login is working fine with adfs throght openam.

Can anyone help me to do login to adfs server through openam using java application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Refer [OpenAM and ADFS2 configuration](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+and+ADFS2+configuration).

The article covers all your questions.

**Update:**

The way I normally do this is to use the OpenSSO / OpenAM Java Fedlet.

Refer [Using Fedlets in Java Web Applications](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index.html#chap-fedlet-java) (Chapter 8).

The code (as per the fedlet) to display the contents of the token looks like:

```
Response samlResp = (Response) map.get(SAML2Constants.RESPONSE); 
Assertion assertion = (Assertion) map.get(SAML2Constants.ASSERTION);
Subject subject = (Subject) map.get(SAML2Constants.SUBJECT);
String entityID = (String) map.get(SAML2Constants.IDPENTITYID);
String spEntityID = (String) map.get(SAML2Constants.SPENTITYID);
NameID nameId = (NameID) map.get(SAML2Constants.NAMEID);
String value = nameId.getValue();
String format = nameId.getFormat();
out.println("<br><br><b>Single Sign-On successful with IDP " 
    + entityID + ".</b>");
out.println("<br><br>");
out.println("<table border=0>");
if (format != null) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td valign=top><b>Name ID format: </b></td>");
    out.println("<td>" + format + "</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}
if (value != null) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td valign=top><b>Name ID value: </b></td>");
    out.println("<td>" + value + "</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}    
String sessionIndex = (String) map.get(SAML2Constants.SESSION_INDEX);
if (sessionIndex != null) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td valign=top><b>SessionIndex: </b></td>");
    out.println("<td>" + sessionIndex + "</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}    

Map attrs = (Map) map.get(SAML2Constants.ATTRIBUTE_MAP);
if (attrs != null) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td valign=top><b>Attributes: </b></td>");
    Iterator iter = attrs.keySet().iterator();
    out.println("<td>");
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String attrName = (String) iter.next();
        Set attrVals = (HashSet) attrs.get(attrName);
        if ((attrVals != null) && !attrVals.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator it = attrVals.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                out.println(attrName + "=" + it.next() + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
    out.println("</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}
out.println("</table>");
```

Comment: they are saying just open the url in browser but if I opened the url via post method I am getting exception  "Error processing AuthnRequest. Null input" then what does it mean is there any need to pass extra parameters to this url?

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? Configure the debug log http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/2012-March/005339.html and see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: when I changed  AuthnRequestsSigned="false"
 and    WantAssertionsSigned="false" in sp.xmlerror is gone and its showing url with SAMLrequest token.

Comment: after authentication to adfs SAML response will come to my openam and openam token will be generated but how I will access that openam token from my java app?

Comment: is it neccessary to install client SDK when want to access the openam url via java application?

Comment: What do you mean by "Client SDK"?

Comment: means OpenAM Client SDK to connect to openam and get sso token which is decoded by openam from saml  response. and my openam acting as service provider and ADFS is IP so what is mean by hosted identity provider.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an OpenAM guru and have never used the Client SDK. I normally do this via the Fedlet.

Comment: ok.. I tried using fedlet but its doing login to openam bcz I have provided IDP as openam while creating fedlet but what if I want to do login to ADFS server not.

Comment: ok.. I tried using fedlet but its doing login to openam and redirecting to fedelate app bcz I have provided IDP as openam while creating fedlet but what if I want to do login to ADFS server. :(

Comment: If you use the Fedlet, you go direct from your Java application either to ADFS or OpenAM depending on how you configure it. My comment about the Fedlet was that that was the only piece of OpenAM I have ever used. Hence I copied the code above to show how to display the token. This may help http://blog.auth360.net/2011/10/09/forgerock-openam-9-5-3-and-ad-fs-2-0-integration-part-1/. Note that there are three parts - all in the blog.