# Import users from ADFS to openam

Tags: adfs2.0, openam

How to import users from ADFS server to openam. I refered this doc

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+and+ADFS2+configuration

where they are saying users which are present on ADFS server must be present on openam.But if

I have thousand of users created on ADFS then can't create them manually on openam.so is

there any way to import the users from adfs server to openam either by accessing openam url

i.e through openam GUI or from java app.

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "import users from ADFS server to openam" can you be more specific. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @nzpcmad  I have edited my question .Plz have a look.

Answer (score 1):

OK - that document is confusing.

The difference between the IP and the SP is that only the IP has a credential store (AD in this case).

So the users only have to exist in AD.

If you look at the diagram, there is no credential store in Network A.

That's the whole point of federation.

**Update:**

Apologies - I seem to have confused some people.

That article refers to [Account Linking](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/Account+Linking) but as per [Using AD FS 2.0 for interoperable SAML 2.0-based federated Web Single Sign-On](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/documents/France/Interop/2010/Using_ADFS2_0_For_Interoperable_SAML_2_0-Based_Federated_SSO.docx&ei=m4-NUOH4DoiTiQeXyIGIDg&usg=AFQjCNHha9CCJPZ3D-hTdxmGM7SKMWj3hg&sig2=SRjfnRCzKZDPcyWJzq7JwA):

"AD FS 2.0 does not support the account linking scenario. Such a scenario can still be achieved in some ways with an appropriate incoming policy."

For federation, there's a good article here:

[ForgeRock OpenAM 9.5.3 and AD FS 2.0 Integration : Part 1](http://blog.auth360.net/2011/10/09/forgerock-openam-9-5-3-and-ad-fs-2-0-integration-part-1/)

but note that this looks at using OpenAM as a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (IdP) and AD FS 2.0 as a SAML 2.0 Service Provider (SP).

There are three parts to this article - all in the blog.

Comment: thank u so much.. one more question when we access the url via post method I am getting exception that I have posted it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025786/login-to-adfs-through-openam-using-java-application/13036485#13036485 link can you plz look at this link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually OpenAM does not store user accounts, they are stored in a so called Identity Repository (currently mostly used is an LDAP Directory Server, RDBMS has some issues yet).

You could retrieve the data from AD and import it in the Identity Repository.

However if you own ADFS and OpenAM why don't you let OpenAM consume the identities from AD by configuring it as an Identity Repository? You may search on the openam user alias ... plenty of explanations there.

Answer (score 0):

About SP and IdP ... users are only AUTHENTICATED at the IdP but the user may exist under a different account on the SP side. Part of Federation/SAML is 'account linking' (not only single sign on) so identities (user accounts) can exist on SP and IdP side